# How can I find the rate of safely scraping or crawling a website without getting blocked?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, rate-limiting

I define rate as the Number of HTTP Requests per unit time.

I don't know the time after which I would get blocked (e.g. 1000 requests per day). I'm trying to determine this rate for any url. How can I accomplish this? What is the strategy that I can employ?

Answer (score 0):

This is something what depends on the site you are scraping. Sometimes it is documented somewhere but very likely not. APIs are better in this case.

So I would suggest a trial and error and add some pause to your scraping and don't let Scrapy run too fast to do not get blocked (or use a custom scraper where you can limit the scraping speed to your pace not Scrapy).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you a simple php script:

```
<?php
$url='<site url>';
$page = file_get_contents($url);
mail('<your email>',  "scrape {$url} response size = " . strlen($page) , ''); 
?>
```

Set the script up thru `cron` to run with initial minimum rate for a day. Say, every 20 min. In a day it will run `24 * 60/20` = `72` (times).

A mail will be sent to you each 20 min with the size of a site that the script scraped. Next day you run it more often (every 15 min) and so on.

If the size drastically changes (diminishes) you've got a sign of scrape blocking. This will be an approximate blocking scrape rate.